# Attempting to Publish message from Android to Raspberry pi using MQTT

Tags: java, android, android-studio, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I own raspberry pi and android smartphone. I am trying to control raspburry pi GPIO with self-made application by android studio. The devices are able connect to each other via MQTT, but when I was trying to publish a message (on/off), it doesn't showed up in the raspberry pi terminal. There is no error detected. I have no clue, what I'm missing here. Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Switch aswitch;
    MqttAndroidClient client;
    TextView subText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
        client = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), "tcp://192.168.2.193:1883",clientId);
        //client = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), "tcp://192.168.43.41:1883",clientId);

    }
    public void Switch(View v){
        aswitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.simpleSwitch1);
        aswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked == true){
                    String topic = "rpi/gpio";
                    String payload = "On";
                    byte[] encodedPayload = new byte[0];
                    try {
                        encodedPayload = payload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(encodedPayload);
                        message.setRetained(true);
                        client.publish(topic, message);
                    } catch (MqttException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else{
                    String topic = "rpi/gpio";
                    String payload = "Off";
                    byte[] encodedPayload = new byte[0];
                    try {
                        encodedPayload = payload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(encodedPayload);
                        message.setRetained(true);
                        client.publish(topic, message);
                    } catch (MqttException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    

    public void conn(View v){

        try {
            IMqttToken token = client.connect();
            token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    setSubscription();
                }
                private void setSubscription() {
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"connection failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69778997/edit) question to include what you've done to debug this. e.g. running `mosquitto_sub -v -t '#'` on the pi to see what is getting published, tailing the mosquitto log so you can see the android app connect and when it publishes (you may need to turn the logging up to see this)

Comment: Also I don't see anywhere in that code where you actually call the `conn()` method to actually start the connection

Comment: `mosquitto_sub -v -t '#'` works, thank Hardillb you nail it!  For the `conn()` I have it there under `try{`. Please advice if you have any suggestion. I have just start learning Java :)

Comment: If you are seeing the messages with the `mosquitto_sub` command then the problem is not with your Android app (assuming it's publishing the right format messages to the right topics)